# Cannot find toolchain for my Armv7l

Tags: angstrom-linux

I am trying to cross-compile from Ubuntu (host) to Armv7l (target) but when i am trying to reach this site (http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/toolchains) in order to download the appropriate toolchain,i get this error "404 Not Found".

Does anyone knows where i can find the toolchain for my system?

Answer (score 0):

Your toolchain is probably here

https://4fe835f16ae6b3c2724bb430809c585acf3bdc3c.googledrive.com/host/0B3Z340LOBulvMG5NRmNlZEppSEE/